# Checking login status while opening app Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am just now learning android. I have created a login page. I want to know how I can check whether the user has logged in while opening the app instead of opening the login screen every time. How do I declare a variable and set its value to check the login and go to the appropriate screen

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save the UserId and UserPassword (you can encrypt and save also).
To achieve this you need to use SharedPreferences.

- On login button click save the UserId and UserPassword as

  string strData = UserId+"," + UserPassword;

//saperated by comma because while login again can split string and validate.

```
    var prefs = 
     Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("ANYFILENAME",FileCreationMode.Private);
     
    var prefEditor = prefs.Edit();
    
    prefEditor.PutString("LoggedInOrNot",strData);
    
    prefEditor.Commit();
```

Now,
every time you just need to read, wheather the data is save or not

//Check this condition in splash screen

```
var preference = GetSharedPreferences("ANYFILENAME", FileCreationMode.Private);
string strLoggedIn = preference.GetString("LoggedInOrNot", string.Empty);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strLoggedIn))
{
StartActivity(typeof(LoginActivity));
}
else
{
StartActivity(typeof(YourActivity));
}
```

This is how you will achieve it, for any doubt or query let me know.If this helps you then give a thubs up.